# find a specific word in a string, case intensive - ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I am new to ruby, I am trying to write a method that checks if the word includes "hello" case insensitive e.g "HelLO" would still be true.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches:

1. [`downcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#downcase-method) before comparing

   ```rb
   str = "HelLO"

   str.downcase.include?('hello')
   #=> true
   ```
2. use case-insensitive [regular rexpression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html)

   ```rb
   str = "HelLO"

   str.match?(/hello/i)
   #=> true
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach is to downcase both string and do the comparing. Like this:

```rb
'HellO'.downcase.include?('hello')
# true
```